# Вызов .so библиотеки в C#

Tags: c#, c++, wsl

Написал небольшую C++ библиотеку с экспортируемым методом. Собираю ее в Dll и метод вызывается без проблем, но мне нужно, чтобы программа работала на Linux, поэтому я собираю библиотеку в Shared Object с помощью msys2 mingw64, но как бы я не пытался, при вызове метода
я получаю исключение:

> Unable to load shared library 'test.so' or one of its dependencies. In
> order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG
> environment variable: libtest.so: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory

Разумеется, я запускаю программу в WSL и указываю активную директорию к папке с библиотекой

```
[DllImport("test.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern IntPtr VerifyCert();
```

Comment: @AlexF То есть мне нужно добавить директорию с библиотекой в LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: Разрядность библиотеки и приложения должны совпадать, убедитесь в этом. Для 64 разрядных рекомендуется конвенция fastcall. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/blob/main/docs/cpp/fastcall.md

Answer (score 0):

Может, всё-таки следует скомпилировать компилятором gcc? Пробовали создать программу с помощью msys2 mingw64 и запустить её в Linux? И не забудьте указать в экспортируемых функциях extern "С":

```
extern "С" char* VerifyCert()
{
....
}
```

И компиляция с флагом -shared